# Bad_weak_ptr caused by call to shared_from_this with multiple inheritence

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, multiple-inheritance, ambiguous, enable-shared-from-this

I am trying to understand why there is a `bad_weak_ptr` exception when calling `shared_from_this`.

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

class parent : public std::enable_shared_from_this<parent>
{
public:
    void compare(std::shared_ptr<parent> const& p2)
    {
        std::cout << (this->shared_from_this() == p2->shared_from_this());
    }
};

class child1 : public parent
{};

class child2 : public parent
{};

class child3 : public child1, public child2
{};

void compare(parent& p1, parent& p2)
{
    std::cout << &p1 << " : " << &p2 << "\n";
    std::cout << (&p1 == &p2);
}

void compare(std::shared_ptr<parent> const& p1, std::shared_ptr<parent> const& p2)
{
    compare(*p1, *p2);
//  p1->compare(p2); // bad_weak_ptr
//  auto p = p1->shared_from_this(); // bad_weak_ptr
}

void compareusingchild(std::shared_ptr<child1> const& c1, std::shared_ptr<child2> const& c2)
{
    compare(c1, c2);
}

int main()
{
    std::shared_ptr<child3> c3 = std::make_shared<child3>();
    try
    {
        compareusingchild(c3, c3);
    }
    catch (std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cout << e.what();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I found that by making `class parent` inheritance virtual, this problem doesn't seem to persist. Why isn't this a compile time error? something like 'ambiguous function call' when it could not find the correct inherited parent?

An API containing just the parent class cannot know in advance the inheritance hierarchy and call to compare method (in parent) will cause run-time error. Is it possible to make such errors compile time detectable?

Comment: This is a diamond problem. Since your inheritance is not virtual `child3` have two components of `parent` (one from `child1` one from `child2`) and as a result you have two components of `std::enable_shared_from_this`. Please note you are using `std::enable_shared_from_this` in incorrect way. When you called `std::make_shared<child3>();` only one version of  `std::enable_shared_from_this` has been initialized.

Comment: i do get a compile error https://onlinegdb.com/rkecnzBBB `error: ‘std::enable_shared_from_this’ is an ambiguous base of ‘child3’` with c++14 but it compiles fine with c++17 :(

Comment: @ustulation I compiled only with MSVS 2017 untill now. Now that you said it, i tried c++ 11 too and it doesn't compile. So this problem is not relevant for my application as its in c++11. I still would like to know what changed in c++17?

Comment: @ustulation surprisingly it compiles: https://godbolt.org/z/Z7MztH

Comment: @MarekR I agree its a diamond problem. Shouldn't the compiler detect it?

Comment: This is more like compiler difference since with C++11 it also compiles: https://godbolt.org/z/LnsXrK

Comment: It also runs without `std::bad_weak_ptr` https://godbolt.org/z/G4t-QE

Comment: @MarekR There is no exeption because call to method shared_from_this are commented out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok Now I see what is the problem.

Diamond problem disables `shared_from_this()`.

Under the hood (for MSVC 2017) you can find something like this:

```cpp
template<class _Yty,
    class = void>
    struct _Can_enable_shared
        : false_type
    {   // detect unambiguous and accessible inheritance from enable_shared_from_this
    };

template<class _Yty>
    struct _Can_enable_shared<_Yty, void_t<typename _Yty::_Esft_type>>
        : is_convertible<remove_cv_t<_Yty> *, typename _Yty::_Esft_type *>::type
    {   // is_convertible is necessary to verify unambiguous inheritance
    };
```

So basically when template is generated, it checks if conversion from `child3 *` to `std::enable_shared_from_this<parent> *` is possible. If it is possible, internal weak pointer is set otherwise nothing is done.

Now since there is an ambiguity simple conversion is not possible  `std::is_convertible` returns false and `shared_from_this` is not enabled (set to proper value).

Here is a proof: https://godbolt.org/z/V2AzLk

```cpp
        std::cout << "Conv child3: " << std::is_convertible<child3*, std::enable_shared_from_this<parent>*>::value << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Conv child2: " << std::is_convertible<child2*, std::enable_shared_from_this<parent>*>::value << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Conv child1: " << std::is_convertible<child1*, std::enable_shared_from_this<parent>*>::value << std::endl;
```

prints:

```
Conv child3: 0
Conv child2: 1
Conv child1: 1
```

So basically ambiguity doesn't cause compilation issue it just doesn't enable this functionality.

Comment: This is what I hate that implicit init of the `weak_ptr` member: if the "magic" doesn't work it won't ever tell you, as deriving from `enable_shared_from_this` is optional. There are many Q on SO about failing `shared_from_this`, notably from private inheritance. Also it won't work if you have a smart ptr to a member and not a base.